# How to transfer data from Amazon S3 to Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, elasticsearch

I am using an EC2 instance and I have enabled the log service of Elastic Load Balancer. The logs are stored in Amazon S3 and I want that data to be used as dataset for Elasticsearch which is present on my EC2 instance. Is there a way I can transfer the data to my EC2 instance or access the data directly from S3 only to be used for Elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 4):

The **[AWS Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)** has commands that make it easy to copy to/from Amazon S3.

You can run them on your EC2 instance to download data from Amazon S3.

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/path/file .
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/path . --recursive
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/path .
```